# Remove empty spaces created by null values in Chart.js

Tags: arrays, chart.js, bar-chart, emptydatatext

I have the following data in the following chart (with undesired empty spaces marked with blue arrows):

```
const dataone = [1, 2, 5, 4, 2];
const datatwo = [2, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const datathree = [2, 3, 3, 2, 4];
const datafour = [null, null, 4, null, null];
const datafive = [null, 2, null, null, null];
```

[image]

How can I remove the empty spaces and still have the null values in the arrays?

You can see and edit all the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/pedroRelvas/NoNullSpacesInChart/tree/master/?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple, just do this in each dataset you want to remove (if there is no such values in the dataset array of course! If there is, is 100% understandable to have empty spaces):

```
data:{
   datasets: [{
            ...
            hidden: true,
            ...
        },],
}
```